# Is there any method through which i can pull data from 10 different schemas in one pyspark script?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

i have some data at SQL server where it is stored in 10 different schemas. Although the table structure is same in all schemas. Is there any method where i can pull all that data in one pyspark script? 
One alternative is create 10 data frames for 10 schemas and then union all, which will require me to hit the sql server 10 times. For instance something like this:

```
df1 = spark.sql("""select id, name, address from schema_1.personal_details""") \
      spark.read(db_details)

df2 = spark.sql("""select id, name, address from schema_2.personal_details""") \
      spark.read(db_details)

df3 = spark.sql("""select id, name, address from schema_3.personal_details""") \
      spark.read(db_details)
```

Like this, 10 different schemas and then doing union.

What i am looking is to collect all data in one/required data frames by hitting the db once maybe by using a for loop or something sort of.

Note: Cannot use sqoop as i have to create 10 different sqoop scripts (as per our architecture).

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the unionall operation on the sql server itself then return the data to spark that way you'll be hitting the db only once. Even if you try to loop through schemas still you'll be hitting db multiple times.

SO you can create the query like this

```
select id, name, address from schema_1.personal_details
union all
select id, name, address from schema_2.personal_details
union all
select id, name, address from schema_3.personal_details

and so on..
```

and then run this query in spark jdbc

```
spark.read.format("jdbc")
.option("url", jdbcUrl)
.option("query", yourUnionallQuery)
.load()
```